# Kendo UI vertical slider top alignment in IE9 not working

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to align the tops of 7 verticle kendo-ui slider widgets
and they don't align in IE9 (FF34 works) unless I set the
max:, min:, smallStep:, and largeStep: all the same.

See example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elbarto99/rhL33xc3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".eqSliderYr").kendoSlider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        min: 2000,
        max: 2015,
        smallStep: 1,
        largeStep: 5,
        showButtons: true,
        increaseButtonTitle: "+ Year",
        decreaseButtonTitle: "- Year",
    });

    $(".eqSliderMon").kendoSlider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        min: 1,
        max: 12,
        smallStep: 1,
        largeStep: 5,
        showButtons: true,
        increaseButtonTitle: "+ Month",
        decreaseButtonTitle: "- Month",
    });
```

...

```
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2nd group of sliders.  All have the same 
    // max:, min:, smallStep, and largeStep settings
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    $(".eq2SliderYr").kendoSlider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        min: 1,
        max: 91,
        smallStep: 1,
        largeStep: 20,
        showButtons: true,
        increaseButtonTitle: "+ Year",
        decreaseButtonTitle: "- Year",
    });

    $(".eq2SliderMon").kendoSlider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        min: 1,
        max: 91,
        smallStep: 1,
        largeStep: 20,
        showButtons: true,
        increaseButtonTitle: "+ Month",
        decreaseButtonTitle: "- Month",
    });
    //...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have IE11 but I've got same bug I guess. Just add this CSS to your sliders:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rhL33xc3/1/

Comment: Thanks j4ro.  This worked in IE9.  I also was able to set the eqSliderMs and eq2SliderMs, max: 999 instead of 59 and it works too.  any number above 90 would cause the vert. slider to have no hash marks and then the tops wouldn't align in IE9, and FF35.  With the "vertical-align: top; I put in the "div.eqSliderYr,div.eqSliderMon,div.eqSliderDay,div.eqSliderHr,div.eqSliderMin,div.eqSliderSec,div.eqSliderMs,
 div.eq2SliderYr,div.eq2SliderMon,div.eq2SliderDay,div.eq2SliderHr,div.eq2SliderMin,div.eq2SliderSec,div.eq2SliderMs {
" css it fixed the problem.